# SQL how to count the number of credit cards that had at least 1,5,10,20 etc transactions in rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping, derived-table

I have a MySQL data set of credit card transactions.

```
create table trans (
  card_id int,
  amount int
);

insert into trans values (1, 1);
insert into trans values (2, 1);
insert into trans values (3, 1);
insert into trans values (4, 1);
insert into trans values (5, 1);
insert into trans values (5, 1);
insert into trans values (6, 1);
insert into trans values (6, 1);
insert into trans values (7, 1);
insert into trans values (7, 1);
insert into trans values (8, 1);
insert into trans values (8, 1);
insert into trans values (8, 1);
insert into trans values (9, 1);
insert into trans values (9, 1);
insert into trans values (9, 1);
insert into trans values (10, 1);
insert into trans values (10, 1);
insert into trans values (10, 1);
insert into trans values (10, 1);
```

I desire to know:

```
1. how many cards were used to make at least 1 transaction
2. how many cards were used to make at least 5 transactions
3. how many cards were used to make at least 10 transactions
4. how many cards were used to make at least 20 transactions
etc...
```

Because the groups overlap, it appears conditional aggregation is a better approach:

```
select sum(cnt >= 1) as trans_1,
       sum(cnt >= 5) as trans_5,
       sum(cnt >= 10) as trans_10,
       sum(cnt >= 20) as trans_20
from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
      from trans
      group by card_id 
      ) d;
```

The problem is the above produces a result set in columns, but I am trying to produce a result set in rows.

The traditional way in MySQL to pivot columns to rows is to use a sequence of select sum() from table union repetitively, but in this case the base data is a derived table, so that method seems to not work here.  Any ideas of how to flip the columns to rows?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f741/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this either by pivoting the rows after the calculation or by doing the calculation on separate rows.  The first should have much better performance:

```
select x.which,
       (case when x.n = 1 then trans_1
             when x.n = 2 then trans_5
             when x.n = 3 then trans_10
             when x.n = 4 then trans_20
        end) as numtransactions
from (select sum(cnt >= 1) as trans_1,
             sum(cnt >= 5) as trans_5,
             sum(cnt >= 10) as trans_10,
             sum(cnt >= 20) as trans_20
      from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
            from trans
            group by card_id 
           ) d
     ) d join
     (select 1 as n, '1 or more' as which union all
      select 2, '5 or more' union all
      select 3, '10 or more' union all
      select 4, '20 or more'
     ) x
order by x.n;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer, but it works.  It's somewhat less optimal in that the query needs to be executed multiple times to do the grouping and counting.

```
select sum(cnt >= 1) as trans_1
from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
      from trans
      group by card_id 
      ) d
UNION ALL
select sum(cnt >= 2) as trans_2
from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
      from trans
      group by card_id 
      ) d
UNION ALL
select sum(cnt >= 3) as trans_10
from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
      from trans
      group by card_id 
      ) d
UNION ALL
select sum(cnt >= 4) as trans_20
from (select card_id, count(*) as cnt
      from trans
      group by card_id 
      ) d;
```